# Allow users to access only terms that he created

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, users

Terms from user that created nodes are stored in vocabulary tags. When user creates new content i would like to allow him to only choose from list of terms he created instead of whole vocabulary.
Is that possible ?

Comment: That tags widget is autocomplete ?

Comment: It can be any widget, as there will be no more then 10-15 tags per user.

Comment: Different widgets need different code approaching, what's the point in changing widgets ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a module that stores authoring information (author, published date and updated date) for the taxonomy term.

This module is views integrated. Exposes authoring information fields (author, published date and updated date) to views configuration (fields/filters/arguments/sorts/relation).

[Taxonomy Term Authoring Information](https://www.drupal.org/project/term_authoring_info)

After installing this module, create a view that filters terms and displays only terms created by the current user then change the field widget to use that view.

Comment: Which module you recommend for using views results in node field ?

Comment: autocomplete deluxe

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/autocomplete_deluxe